# Salesforce Mobile SDK error when fetch plugin SalesforceMobileSDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, cordova

I've been trying to create a hybrid application with sdk but at a point of creation it gives me the following error:

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin via registry.
>
> Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
>
> Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>
> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>   npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-06-15T09_37_27_170Z-debug.log

The connection works correctly, I do not use any proxy and I have also tried copy/paste the line that puts in the doc.

I am new to Cordova and I do not know if I have something wrong, I only follow the doc guide. If you need more information ask me.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the version of cordova to 6.4.0